# Launch Octave from my Android application

Tags: android, android-intent, octave

I want my android app to launch GNU Octave and have Octave run a particular Matlab script. The script should do some signal processing with a some Wave input file and create some Wave output files. Input and output filepaths should be handed over to the Matlab script via my app. GNU Octave is already installed on my Nexus 5. I am using the Android SDK on Eclipse with Android SDK Tools 23.0.2.

This is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.fhdw.smartnavi"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_logo1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="de.fhdw.smartnavi.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"  >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And this is the code of my MainActivity.java:

```
    package de.fhdw.smartnavi;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Timer;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.SeekBar;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getActionBar().hide();

        initialize();

        }

    public void initialize(){

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setClassName("com.octave.main", "com.octave.main.octaveDownloaderActivity");
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    }
```

I am getting a permission error for launching the Octave Activity.

What do I have to do to get Octave launched from my app? The Android developer documentation doesn't really help with such permissions, it only talks about setting the typical permissions on system access (call phone, read files etc.).

I hope I don't have to get the Octave source code, edit the Octave Manifest itself and recompile and somehow manually install Octave on my phone in a complicated way, only to be allowed to run Octave from my own app?

BTW, I now also modified the launching code in the MainActivity to this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.octave.main", "com.octave.main.octaveDownloaderActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

I got the idea on what package and class to load from the Octave-for-Android source repo manifest:

https://github.com/corbinlc/octave4android/blob/master/octave/OctaveMainPackage/AndroidManifest.xml

And this is the LogCat output when launching my app via Eclipse on my Nexus 5:

```
    07-22 12:12:33.434: D/dalvikvm(15879): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 58K, 1% free 17132K/17224K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
    07-22 12:12:33.444: D/AndroidRuntime(15879): Shutting down VM
    07-22 12:12:33.444: W/dalvikvm(15879): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415dfba8)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879): Process: de.fhdw.smartnavi, PID: 15879
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.fhdw.smartnavi/de.fhdw.smartnavi.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.octave.main/.octaveDownloaderActivity } from ProcessRecord{433b1580 15879:de.fhdw.smartnavi/u0a97} (pid=15879, uid=10097) not exported from uid 10094
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.octave.main/.octaveDownloaderActivity } from ProcessRecord{433b1580 15879:de.fhdw.smartnavi/u0a97} (pid=15879, uid=10097) not exported from uid 10094
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2096)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1419)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)        
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at de.fhdw.smartnavi.MainActivity.initialize(MainActivity.java:44)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at de.fhdw.smartnavi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    07-22 12:12:33.444: E/AndroidRuntime(15879):    ... 11 more
```

As you see, there is a launch permission error. Strangely, I don't get this error when I try to launch Mozilla Firefox instead of Octave.

What do I have to change to launch Octave from my app?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I now found out via the package manager that I should be using the package "com.octave" instead of "com.octave.main". You can retrieve the launch intent for the package with the PackageManager.

So the next problem now is to hand over the args to the activity, i.e. to tell Octave to run a particular script, e.g. "test.m". This doesn't work with

```
...
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.octave");
...
i.putExtra("args", "test.m");
startActivity(i);
```

So it seems that Octave's launch activity does not handle args the way Firefox would do.

What are the right extras to put into the intent here?